# Programatically Registering Spring Components with Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that acts as an agent to collect metrics from other Spring Boot applications (clients). I created a traditional JAR of the agent (Non-fat JAR) and added it to the `pom.xml` of client. However, I have to modify client code to include `@ComponentScan` to detect Spring Beans of my agent.

How can I register the components of the agent with Spring, without any modification to client code?

Answer (score 0):

annotate a method with @Bean to return the class you're referring to load your custom class as a bean in Springboot Application java file.

Comment: Ok, I can do what you say by creating a @Configuration class in my agent. But how will the configuration class get registered with Spring?

Comment: Speciality of Springboot is the auto configuration, which happens if you annotate your class with @Configuration. Rest springboot will take care of the registration.

Comment: Provided the @Configuration class is in the same or sub package of the main class annotated as SpringBootApplication. If you relook at my question, my configuration class is in a different agent application, which has been brought in via Maven dependency.